# How to trigger click event into DOM loaded through Ajax but NOT APPENDED

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, click

I need to trigger click on all matches elements ant then read the dom generated into the dom saved into a variable, how can I do this without to append the dom get it from ajax call?

Or how can I load the dom into some hidden browser tab to make possible window and document events bubbles?

```js
let url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07VHXT1R3';
  $.get( url ).then(resp => {
    let dom = $( resp );

    //images preload 
    dom.find('#altImages li input').each(function(){
      // this would generate other elements inside the dynamic dom,
      // but this is stored into a variable 
      $(this).trigger('click');
    });

    let images = [];
    dom.find('li.image img').each(function(){
      // this would have to read the images generated
      // but only read one element that comes already rendered 
      images.push( $(this).data('old-hires') || this.src );
    });

[ ... ]
```

Specifically, I need to bubble into a dom NOT rendered and without window and document objects bonded

Does somebody have an idea of how to do it without crash the RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with regex

```js
let images = dom.text().match(/(?<="hiRes":")([^"]+)(?=")/gi).filter( (v, i, s) => { return s.indexOf(v) === i });
```